# cleos system newaccount result in "assertion failure with message: ram market does not exist"

Tags: cleos

I'm using local single-node testnet and followed the steps stated in
[bios-boot-sequence](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/bios-boot-sequence)

When I try to create new account by cleos system newaccount, I got below error:

```
Error 3050003: eosio_assert_message assertion failure
Error Details:
assertion failure with message: ram market does not exist
```

Can someone shine some light on this issue? I searched all over with no luck.

Comment: did you upload the relevant `eosio.*` contracts? eosio.ram, eosio.ramfee, eosio.token

Comment: I've uploaded eosio.bios, eosio.msig, eosio.token and eosio.system contract and created accounts: eosio.bpay, eosio.msig, eosio.names, eosio.ram, eosio.ramfee, eosio.saving, eosio.stake, eosio.token, eosio.vpay and eosio.system in cleaning EOS blockchain. Then get the ram market error when I try to create new account by using cleos system newaccount.

Comment: i believe the docs have been updated since, maybe now it works https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/bios-boot-sequence